# Getting name of all nested HOC wrappers and base component inside an HOC

Tags: reactjs, high-order-component

I've seen packages and libraries being able to `console.log` the HOCs + base component. I'm very confused as to how to implement it, because of the following:

- class components have their name defined as `component.displayName`
- functional components have `component.name`
- HOCs don't have a standard way of getting names of nested HOCs and components

For example a sample HOC

```
function NamePrinter(Wrapped) {
  return (class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
      console.log(`the name of this component is ${Wrapped.displayName || Wrapped.name}`)
    }
    render() {
      return <Wrapped {...this.props} />
    }
  })
}
```

Which is really as far as I understand how to get. For example, `react-redux` has its own convention on [getting the name](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/2d5ee79627b6e2dc3ff2e23a395091334a64ef28/src/components/connect.js#L288), but that means I can only go "one layer deep" when searching for a name.

If I have a component wrapped as such:

```
NamePrinter(connect(() => ({}), null)(withStyles({})(React.memo(MyComponent))))
```

How can I `console.log` using my example HOC

```
connect(withStyles(React.memo(MyComponent)))
```

or something similar that has the same expressiveness?

Answer (score 0):

Closest algorithm that I could get. As noted earlier, there's no standard way to expose the wrapped component. for `material-ui`, it's called `Naked`, while `react-redux` is `WrappedComponent`. Unoptimized algorithm

```
// assuming material-ui and react-redux only
function getDisplayName(component) {
    function getName(type) {
        let str = "";
        if (type.displayName) {
            str += "(" + type.displayName;
        } else if (type.name) {
            str += "(" + type.name;
        }

        if (type.Naked && getName(type.Naked)) {
            str += getName(type.Naked);
        } else if (type.WrappedComponent && getName(type.WrappedComponent)) {
            str += getName(type.WrappedComponent);
        } else if (type.render && getName(type.render)) {
            str += getName(type.render);
        } else if (typeof type === "string") {
            str += type;
        } else if (type.type && getName(type.type)) {
            str += getName(type.type);
        }
        return str;
    }

    let currStr = getName(component);
    const openParenCount = Array.from(currStr).filter(el => el === "(").length;
    const closeParenCount = Array.from(currStr).filter(el => el === ")").length;
    return (
        currStr + [...Array(openParenCount - closeParenCount)].map(el => ")").join("")
    )
}
```